# Json to cvs using python

Tags: python, json, csv

I'm trying to convert json to csv, but the code have **"header"**With my current knowladge I can't covert it into csv, because I don't now hot to handle "headers":
`

```
{
"__metadata": {
"uri": "http://ip:port/vvv/v1/folders?page=1&pagesize=50"
},
"first": {
"__deferred": {
"uri": "http://ip:port/vvv/v1/folders?page=1&pagesize=50"
}
},
"last": {
"__deferred": {
"uri": "http://ip:port/vvv/v1/folders?page=1&pagesize=50"
}
},
"entries": [
```

`

And the rest of code looks like this:

`

```
 {
"__metadata": {
"uri": "http://ip:port/vvv/v1/folders/13483"
},
"cuid": "AfbTJW3iTE1MkiLULzA6P58",
"name": "Foldername1",
"description": "",
"id": "13483",
"type": "Folder",
"ownerid": "12",
"updated": "Wed Mar 01 09:14:23 CET 2017"
},
  {
"__metadata": {
"uri": "http://ip:port/vvv/v1/folders/523"
},
"cuid": "AS1oZEJAynpNjZIaZK2rc7g",
"name": "foldername2",
"description": "",
"id": "523",
"type": "Folder",
"ownerid": "10",
"updated": "Wed Jan 18 00:11:06 CET 2017"
},
  {
"__metadata": {
"uri": "http://ip:port/vvv/v1/folders/5356"
},
"cuid": "AeN4lEu0h_tAtnPEjFYxwi8",
"name": "foldername",
"description": "",
"id": "5356",
"type": "Folder",
"ownerid": "12",
"updated": "Fri Feb 10 17:28:53 CET 2017"
}
]
}
```

`

How can I convert above code into csv? How I can deal with **"header"**?

Comment: Where is your `Python` code? Share it as well

Comment: I tried many codes, but after all I enden with nothing. I mean I started with trimming the response, then with converting and all in all I got nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's `json` and `csv` libraries should handle this for you. Just load the json data in and access the `entries` tag directly. From there you can enumerate all the data and write it to a csv file.

This example shows how to also write all of the data in `dataprovider` before writing the `expression` list:

```
import json
import csv


data = """{
    "dataprovider": {
        "id": "DP0",
        "name": "Query 1",
        "dataSourceId": "5430",
        "dataSourcePrefix": "DS0",
        "dataSourceType": "unv",
        "updated": "2010-12-03T13:07:43.000Z",
        "duration": 1,
        "isPartial": "false",
        "rowCount": 1016,
        "flowCount": 1,
        "dictionary": {
            "expression": [{
                "@dataType": "String",
                "@qualification": "Dimension",
                "id": "DP0.DOa5",
                "name": "Lines",
                "description": "Product line. Each line contains a set of categories.",
                "dataSourceObjectId": "DS0.DOa5",
                "formulaLanguageId": "[Lines]"
            },
            {
                "@dataType": "Numeric",
                "@qualification": "Measure",
                "@highPrecision": "false",
                "id": "DP0.DO93",
                "name": "Sales revenue",
                "description": "Sales revenue $ - $ revenue of SKU sold",
                "dataSourceObjectId": "DS0.DO93",
                "formulaLanguageId": "[Sales revenue]",
                "aggregationFunction": "Sum"
            }]
        },
        "query": "SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE"
    }
}
"""

my_json = json.loads(data)

entries = my_json['dataprovider']['dictionary']['expression']

header_1 = my_json['dataprovider'].keys()
header_1.remove("dictionary")
data_1 = [(k, str(my_json['dataprovider'][k])) for k in header_1]

header_2 = sorted(entries[0].keys())

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    # Write initial header information
    csv_output.writerows(data_1)

    # Write an empty row
    csv_output.writerow([])

    # Write list information
    csv_output.writerow(header_2)

    for entry in entries:
        csv_output.writerow([' '.join(str(entry.get(col, '')).splitlines()) for col in header_2])
```

The CSV file would then look something like:

```
updated,2010-12-03T13:07:43.000Z
name,Query 1
dataSourceType,unv
rowCount,1016
isPartial,false
dataSourceId,5430
query,SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE
duration,1
flowCount,1
dataSourcePrefix,DS0
id,DP0

@dataType,@qualification,dataSourceObjectId,description,formulaLanguageId,id,name
String,Dimension,DS0.DOa5,Product line. Each line contains a set of categories.,[Lines],DP0.DOa5,Lines
Numeric,Measure,DS0.DO93,Sales revenue $ - $ revenue of SKU sold,[Sales revenue],DP0.DO93,Sales revenue
```

---

If you are getting different JSON, you need to manually decide which part to extract, for example:

```
entries = my_json['documents']['document']
```

Comment: Ok, but my json code is stored in variable and when my code is like
(response is a respons from http server):
`import json
import csv

data = response`

I get following error: **TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'dict'**

Comment: You should just need `entries = response['entries']` and remove `data` and `my_json`

Comment: than you, I guess it wors properly.

Comment: O but when code is like:
`{
  "documents": {
    "document": [
      {
        "id": 5358,
        "cuid": "AZx1nlTlCMdCvyJ6bWUTC5I",
        "name": "Chart Demo",
        "description": "lorem",
        "folderId": 5357
},
      {
        "id": 11813,
        "cuid": "AT0bvTNuEFBAuTc_qzIhx84",
        "name": "hyplink1",
        "folderId": 11812
      }
    ]
  }
}`
How I can resolve this? Because i get error TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: I have updated the script to auto create the headers based on the available data. To then modify it to your new JSON data, you could change it to `entries = my_json['documents']['document']`

Comment: I guess I have to ask for help once again. In this case json return:
`'description': 'loremipsunloremipsunloremipsunloremipsune.\n\nVersion 13\n\nloremipsunloremipsun \n\loremipsun',`
How can I remove **\n\r\**? Bacause string functions don't work.

Comment: You could modify the writerow as follows: `csv_output.writerow([' '.join(entry.get(col, '').splitlines()) for col in header])`. This would first split the text into a list of lines and then join them back together with a space between them instead.

Comment: Sadly, I've got following error: **AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'splitlines'**
My code:
`result = urllib.request.urlopen( urllib.request.Request(documentUrl,None,headers) )
reponse=json.loads(result.read().decode('utf-8'))
data=reponse
entries = reponse['universes']['universe']
header = sorted(entries[1].keys())
with open('C:\\Users\\Administrator\\output6.csv', 'w') as f_output:
csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
csv_output.writerow(header)
for entry in entries:
print(entries)
csv_output.writerow([' '.join(entry.get(col, '').splitlines()) for col in header])`

Comment: It just means one of the dictionary entries was in integer. Wrapping the call in `str()` should work: `csv_output.writerow([' '.join(str(entry.get(col, '')).splitlines()) for col in header])`

Comment: once again thanks! a lot have a lot of practise to reach your level of knowladge. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunaltely, I have another issue. Do you know haw to handle this data:
`{
"dataprovider": {
"id": "DP0",
"name": "Query 1",
"dataSourceId": "5430",
"dataSourcePrefix": "DS0",
"dataSourceType": "unv",
"updated": "2010-12-03T13:07:43.000Z",
"duration": 1,
"isPartial": "false",
"rowCount": 1016,
"flowCount": 1,
"dictionary": {
"expression": [
{
"@dataType": "String",
"@qualification": "Dimension",
"id": "DP0.DOa5",
"name": "Lines",
"description": "Product line. Each line contains a set of categories.",
"dataSourceObjectId": "DS0.DOa5",
"formulaLanguageId": "[Lines]"
},`

Comment: `{
"@dataType": "Numeric",
"@qualification": "Measure",
"@highPrecision": "false",
"id": "DP0.DO93",
"name": "Sales revenue",
"description": "Sales revenue $ - $ revenue of SKU sold",
"dataSourceObjectId": "DS0.DO93",
"formulaLanguageId": "[Sales revenue]",
"aggregationFunction": "Sum"
}
]
},
"query": "SELECT ... FROM  ... WHERE"
}
}`

Comment: I'm getting some data with following code, but, data, is not complete:
`result = urllib.request.urlopen( urllib.request.Request(documentUrl,None,headers) )
reponse=json.loads(result.read().decode('utf-8'))
data=reponse
entries = reponse ['dataprovider']['dictionary']['expression']
header = sorted(entries[0].keys())
with open('C:\\output7.csv', 'w') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
csv_output.writerow(header)
for entry in entries:
csv_output.writerow([' '.join(str(entry.get(col, '')).splitlines()) for col in header])`

Comment: Ok, I've just applied your changes. First time I got error:
**my_json = json.loads(data)TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'dict'**

then I changed the code as you suggested ealier:
`data=reponse
#my_json = json.loads(data)
entries = data['dataprovider']['dictionary']['expression']
header_1 = data['dataprovider'].keys()
header_1.remove("dictionary")
#inventory["backpack].remove("dagger")
data_1 = [(k, str(data['dataprovider'][k])) for k in header_1]
header_2 = sorted(entries[0].keys())`
But I got error:
**'dict_keys' object has no attribute 'remove'**

Comment: I guess that I solved the problem. I rebuilded line:
**`header_1 = my_json['dataprovider'].keys()`**
to
**`header_1 = list(my_json['dataprovider'].keys())`**
Could you possibly take a look at it? Is it correct?

Comment: I suggest you start another question as it is getting a bit confusing. Copy the script and data from this one.

Comment: It would be easier if you gave the `documentUrl`, that way I could recreate your problem.